# Object Read of NY Times to Draw Article Table in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have the perfect query to provide a list of NFL articles from 2017 to 2018 from the NYT API.

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
url += '?' + $.param({
    'api-key': "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    'q': "NFL",
    'begin_date': "20180101",
    'end_date': "20181101",
    'sort': "newest",
    'fl': "headline",
    'facet_field': "article"
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function(err) {
    throw err;
});
```

I tried consoling "results.docs[x].headline.main", to get just a list of headlines but but it throws an error.

The ulimate desired result is as follows

```
<div>
    <p>headline 1: "Phillies win again"</p>
    <p>headline 2: "New Quarter Back for Dolphins"</p>
    <p>headline 3: "NY Giants go up for sale"</p>
    <p>headline 4: "Running back trips over hotdog"</p>
</div>
```

I've even tried putting it into a variable as both results and response, but no luck. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You might want to edit out that api key.

Comment: I guess you read that, but read it again and check your parameters, especially `facet_field`... [NYT article_search API](https://developer.nytimes.com/article_search_v2.json#/Documentation/GET/articlesearch.json)

Comment: The query works, my challenge is extrapolating a list of only headlines to use in <tr> or <p> elements.

Comment: Then why did you ask about the API ? Give us your **parameters**, what you **get**, what you **want to get**.

Comment: @JackBashford actually editing it out doesn't help, we can still see it in the edit history, probably better to delete this question and create a new one (it's anyhow neutral at this time)

Comment: @JackBashford It's a shiny rock, and not exactly the answer to my question. The API is a freebie. I don't necessarily care about it.

Comment: "_tried consoling_" Where? "_it throws an error_" What is the error message?

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Did you read the post completely? I didn't ask about the API, how did you arrive at that conclusion? Again, I asked how to specifically extract "headlines" from results object. The parameters IS headline..

Comment: We don't know what the returned body looks like, how could we help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was in the way the JSON result was being decoded.

```
function buildQueryURL() {
var queryURL = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?";
var queryParams = { "api-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" };
queryParams.q = "NFL";
queryParams.begin_date = "20170101";
queryParams.end_date = "20180101";
return queryURL + $.param(queryParams);
}
function updatePage(NFLNews) {
var numArticles = 3

for (var i = 0; i < numArticles; i++) {
var article = NFLNews.response.docs[i];
var headline = article.headline;
console.log(headline.main)
var headlinelink = article.web_url;
console.log(headlinelink)
}
}

var queryURL = buildQueryURL();
$.ajax({
url: queryURL,
method: "GET"
}).then(updatePage);
```

I had to declare and join each tier of results to weed out just the main headline from each iteration of the docs array. I was not only able to weed out headlines but the associated link for each.